# styling the layout outline

Tags: android, styles

The problem: A `LinearLayout` is to have a different background(whitish color) with a dark outline.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape = "rectangle">
  <corners
      android:radius="2dp"
      android:topRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

What I tried: The following code is being referred to as an `"android:background"` element in the Layout file. Doing this does not allow my `LinearLayout` to have the whitish background I desired but the dark outline is obtained. Any ideas on how I can achieve both ?
Do help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape = "rectangle">
  <corners
      android:radius="2dp"
      android:topRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#000000" />
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:angle="90"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your `LinearLayout` inside a `FrameLayout`. Give the `FrameLayout` black background. Give the `LinearLayout` white background. Set `LinearLayout's` margin to `1dp`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        ....
        ....

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thats a smart way i guess!